# looking for Eloquent [Capsule::select] return indexed array (not just order numbers)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm exceuting this query....

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
```

[...]

```
$sql = "SELECT
blabla";

$clients = Capsule::select($sql);
dd($clients);
```

From this i get something like this:

```
[0]=>
  array(4) {
["house_rec_by_class"]=>
string(8) "-1250.00"
["client_name"]=>
string(11) "lalala"
["client_id"]=>
string(19) "800001D1-14037201481"
["contract_stage"]=>
string(4) "Live"
}
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
   ["house_rec_by_class"]=>
string(7) "-250.00"
["client_name"]=>
string(15) "lolololo"
["client_id"]=>
string(19) "80000180-13939692362"
["contract_stage"]=>
string(4) "Live"
}
```

Now what i'd like is to get this same array, with the [client_id] in the keys, instead of just consecutive numbers... like

```
["800001D1-14037201481"]=> ['client_name' => 'lalalala', '...'],
["80000180-13939692362"]=> ['client_name' => 'lolololo', '...']
```

I know i can re-loop the array and assign the keys, just was curious if there is a better way.. 
Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

You need something like thit:

```
foreach ($clients as $elem) {
    $id = $elem['client_id'];
    $newClients[$id]['client_name'] = $elem['client_name']; 
    $newClients[$id]['contract_stage'] = $elem['contract_stage'];
    // etc
}
```

You now have a new Array $newClients as expected. I would suggest you to use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if  every element exists.

Comment: Thanks Adam.. yes, i knew i could do this (it's written in the question), i just wanted to look for an eloquent solution like `code` $clients = Capsule::select($sql)->toArray()->usingIndex(['client_id']);`code`

Comment: @rrubiorr81 I'm really hoping you will find what you looking for. That said I don't think you will since it is some really specific job you're asking. You might want do create your own function. Hope it helped.